# Relative path in website with sub-directories

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, path, subdirectory

I want to develop project sites on my Mac's apache server and then upload to the ISP server when ready to launch. I run into trouble when the site has sub-directories. If my link statement uses a relative path:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/site.css" type="text/css"/>`
It doesn't work for sub-directories which need: `href="../css/site.css"`

If I use absolute paths (which work on the ISP's server):
    `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/site.css" type="text/css"/>`
it doesn't work for sub-directories on my apache server.

This is the same problem for images and javascript links. There must be a solution that allows developers to build "one" version of the site and move it to the ISP's server without changing all the path commands. I keep looking for an answer but so far I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue in porting websites.  I don't know if this is the best answer, but I use a server-side script to get the relative root and include using that as an absolute path.

```
<?php
    $rootaccess = $_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    include ($rootaccess.'/_sys/alpha.php');
?>
```

This is the include for a PHP header, but it might work for you like this:

```
<?php
    $rootaccess = $_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php 
         echo $rootaccess;
         ?>/dir1/file.ext" />
```

Comment: Joshua, I guess I'm  getting into deeper water here but I really want to solve this. I tried implementing your code, particularly the 2nd version, but I didn't get any change - page is still un-styled and the JavaScripts don't work. Could you give me specifics of how to implement your script?

Comment: This is just one example.  For starters, can you use PHP on your server?  Or do you need to use JavaScript?  The path returned by SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT might not be what you need.  You'll need to figure out what works on your server.  Try $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]?